# How to get the largest image based on a thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have the URL access of the thumbnail of an image. Now, I want to get the largest image based on the thumbnail image on the URL but I can't locate this largest image.

I checked the wordpress image sizes and saw that the largest image is 1024x1024. My image is:

**www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017-04-sample-image-370x370.jpg**

I tried to change the dimension to:

**www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017-04-sample-image-1024x1024.jpg**

But, it did not work as I expected. Also, I searched the image name in products and media gallery but can't find it.

Is there a way do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `the_post_thumbnail()`. It allows you to specify the size you want:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

```
// without parameter -> Post Thumbnail (as set by theme using set_post_thumbnail_size())
the_post_thumbnail();

the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)

the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions
```

Source for example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails